# Pouring Lava and Water from a bucket

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got a weird problem all of a sudden. As of yesterday, I've noticed a problem: I can't pour items from a bucket correctly. I can pick water and lava up, but when I go to pour them, it simply disappears and nothing happens. I can however click again and get the lava/ water back up in the bucket, even though it shows nothing there.

The problem just randomly started happening, so I'm not sure what's up. Everyone else can pour water/ lava just fine except for me. I didn't make any modifications of any sort from the previous hour it was working to the time the problem started. I do have build rights in the server as well.

Any thoughts to this?

Comment: If you pour it and relog, does it appear?

Comment: Are you trying to pour water in the nether?

Comment: I've had this happen before, it also sometimes makes empty buckets pour also, so be careful if you're handling lava.  Emptying and filling a bucket with the same source that was in it when it went crazy fixes it for me.

Comment: What version of the game?

Comment: It is fixed now! Taken from the forums _The Bucket issue should be fixed now. It was a permissions conflict between two plugins._

Comment: @camiloqp why not post that as an answer, then? It's perfectly okay to answer your own question!

Comment: When it happened to me, I was playing vanilla...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bucket issue was a conflict between two plugins and has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a slow computer, that will happen. Try changing the render distance to short or tiny. That should make it load better, and then try it.